# Diagrama E/R y Diseño en la base de datos con MySQL, ¿es correcto?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, diagrama-er

estoy en pleno desarrollo de una aplicación web para un proyecto final y nos dieron de base el siguiente diagrama E/R.
[image: diagrama e/r]

El problema es que yo con estos diagramas me hago bastante lio e intentado pasarlo a una base de datos MySQL para poder empezar con el desarrollo del código PHP, y antes de comenzar me gustaría cerciorarme de que esta correctamente hecho ya que si no todo lo que haga a partir de ahora no va  a servir para nada. Este es el diseño de la base de datos:
[image: Diseño de la base de datos]

Esto sería todo, muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Tu pregunta es si el diagrama de arriba es equivalente al de abajo ??

Comment: La relación profesores-grupos es 
*muchos a muchos*, necesitas una tabla intermedia.